# Ruby on Rails DynamoDB AWS SDK v2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to set up DynamoDB with my Rails app. I am on rails 4 and I am using aws sdk v2. I want to query items from the database called 'RoomRaw'.

In my Gemfile:

```
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'
```

In config/initializers/aws.rb:

```
Aws.config({
  access_key_id: 'xxxxxxxx',
  secret_access_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
  region: 'ap-southeast-1'
})
```

In my controller:

```
dynamo_db = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new
dynamo_db.query({
  table_name: 'RoomRaw',
  key_conditions: {
    '_id' => {
      comparison_operattor: 'EQ',
      attribute_value_list: ['12345']      
    }
  }
})
```

I am getting the following error:

```
uninitialized constant WelcomeController::Aws
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be a couple of minor issues.

- Uninitialized constant error - Restart your Rails app after adding the gem dependency on `aws-sdk`.
- The configuration in v2 of the SDK has changed slightly from v1. In version 2, `Aws.config` is not a method, it is a vanilla Ruby hash.

Try the following:

```
Aws.config.update({
  access_key_id: 'xxxxxxxx',
  secret_access_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
  region: 'ap-southeast-1'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should restart the rails server. Initializers are loaded only on start.

Comment: i just restarted the server, now i'm getting this error instead - /config/initializers/aws.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)

Comment: You need to check the documentation of Aws, because you're using that wrong in your initializer.

Answer (score 0):

Put the settings in following way then restart your server

```
AWS.config(
 access_key_id: 'your_access_key',
 secret_access_key: 'your_secret_access_key'
)
```

NameError: uninitialized constant AWS

If you receive this error, you likely have upgraded to version 2 of the aws-sdk gem unintentionally. Version 2 uses the Aws namespace, not AWS. This allows version 1 and version 2 to be used in the same application.

See this [blog post](http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/TxFKSK2QJE6RPZ/Upcoming-Stable-Release-of-AWS-SDK-for-Ruby-Version-2) for more information.

Comment: i get config/initializers/aws.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant AWS (NameError)  when i use upper case AWS

Comment: is there another way i can do this?

Comment: "AWS to Aws", I just edited my answer, please re try

Comment: i get /config/initializers/aws.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError) with Aws

Comment: can you try with: AWS.config({
  access_key_id:          '...',
  secret_access_key:      '...',
  region:                 'us-east-1',
  dynamo_db_endpoint:     'localhost',
  dynamo_db_port:         8000
  }
)